# How do I pass a parameter to a SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

******Calling to queries in C#:****

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SqlR",connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
OleDbParameter parameter = new OleDbParameter("@kalpiNum",s);//the operators
cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter); rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I not see the operator
**The query:**

```
SELECT BO.MISHPAHA AS MISHPAHA,
       BO.PRATI AS PRATI,
       TM.LongShem AS LongShem,
       TM.SHEM AS SHEM,**
       TM.semel AS semel,
       TM.OT AS OT,
       (select SUM(KOLOT)
        from TOZAOTR
        where MUAMAD=BO.ZEUT AND kalpi =@kalpiNum) AS Total,
       (select sum(kolot)
        FROM TOZAOTR
        WHERE kalpi =@kalpiNum) AS SuMall,
       ROUND((Total/(SuMall+0.00001))*100,2) AS pre
FROM (MUAMADIM AS MU LEFT JOIN BOHARIM AS BO ON MU.ZEUT=BO.ZEUT)
LEFT JOIN TMIFLAGA AS TM ON MU.MIFLAGA=TM.SEMEL;
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: What do you want? Do you see "the query" in the debugger or do you want to have this query?

Comment: I guess you should just change this line by removing the '@' in the parameter name : OleDbParameter parameter = new OleDbParameter("kalpiNum", s);

Comment: What database and provider are you using?  It may not support named parameters.